# How to save audio file after recording either locally or firebase in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a voice recording feature in my app but don't know where to save this file and where to see this file? And also tell me how to store this file in Firebase Storage? 
I am using Firebase Storage in my app.
Here is my Code.

Code used in UploadRecordedAudio.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
@import FirebaseStorage;
@import FirebaseAuth;

@interface UploadRecordedAudio : UIViewController<AVAudioRecorderDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
- (IBAction)btnRecord:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *record;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stop;
- (IBAction)btnStop:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *play;
- (IBAction)btnPlay:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRStorage *storage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FIRStorageReference *storageRef;

@end
```

This code is used in UploadRecordedAudio.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
    [_play setEnabled:NO];
    [_stop setEnabled:NO];

    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject], @"MyAudioMemo.m4a", nil];

    NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
    //NSLog(@"HERE: %@",pathComponents);
    //Setup Audio Session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    //Define the Recorder Settings...
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    //Initiate and Prepare the Recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];

    NSData *aData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents]];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/MyFolder"];
    NSLog(@"%@",dataPath);
    [aData writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];
}

- (IBAction)btnRecord:(id)sender
{
    //Stop the audio player before Recording...
    if (player.playing)
    {
        [player stop];
    }
    if (!recorder.recording)
    {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        //Start Recording
        [recorder record];
        [_record setTitle:@"Pause Recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [recorder pause];
        [_record setTitle:@"Resume Recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    [_stop setEnabled:YES];
    [_play setEnabled:NO];
}
- (IBAction)btnPlay:(id)sender
{
    if (!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [_stop setEnabled:NO];
    [_play setEnabled:YES];
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Done" message:@"Finish playing the recording!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:action];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)btnStop:(id)sender
{
    [recorder stop];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
}

@end

Please help me to solve this??? Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: changed MyAudioMemo.m4a to **MyAudioMemo.mp4**